# How to add pre-defined values on "Found in Environment" field

Tags: azure-devops

AzureDevOps has a a filed called "Found In Environment".

I want to add this to my work items, however I would like to setup a predefined list of values that the user should select.

I can do this by adding a new custom filed, but It would be strange to add custom filed for a filed that AzureDevOps already have.

Question: Is there any way to configure a predefined set of values for already existing filed?

[image: AzureDevOps Found In Environment]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Azure DevOps just support users to customize the values for any system picklist(except the reason field) such as Severity, Activity, Priority, etc. You can refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-156-update#customize-system-picklist-values) to get the information about customize system picklist values.

As my test, the Found in Environment field only support one default value, not picklist items.
[image]

So according to your question, some fileds can configure set of values for already existing field, but not the Found in Environment field.

Or you can use XML to customize your own process and fields value by your rule. Below is a simple sample about how to definition a work item picklist items in XML.

In addition, only after Migrate from tfs to azure devops, you will have edit xml options. About XML, you can refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=azure-devops-2019)

```
<FIELD name="Priority" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority" type="Integer" reportable="dimension">
    <HELPTEXT>Business importance. 1=must fix; 4=unimportant.</HELPTEXT>
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="1" />
      <LISTITEM value="2" />
      <LISTITEM value="3" />
      <LISTITEM value="4" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
    <DEFAULT from="value" value="2" />
  </FIELD>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  
I found the option you are referring to!     

But as you wrote in your answer, its only possible to add/change applicable values if the filed is defined already as a list.   

Its not possible to add a list of accepted values for a filed that is not list!

Comment: Because these fields are provided by Microsoft, their format is as designed, so we can't change it by ourselves. But we still have two workaround that you can try. The first is, as my answer said, you can use XML to design your own process and the fields format. The second is, I can help you create a suggestion ticket about this request, Microsoft will collect these suggestion tickets, and will publish them which have much more counts of vote.